# Analyze seasonality in hourly time series data and get the confidence score

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, time-series, arima

I have a 1000's of different hourly time series data and I want to analyze seasonality in historical data like weekly or daily so that I can put a hyperparameter seasonality with DAILY or WEEKLY or both in my bq ARIMA model while forecasting prediction

[hourly time series for a month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhm17.png)
from this image we can see that there is weekly drop in data so we have weekly seasonality
I used MSTL to get the seasonal decompose of data and also took the acf of that as its a hourly data I added a lag of 168 0r 336 to show 2 weekends of data but I'm stuck now how to enhance it further to calculate a confidence score based on which I can be sure that is there any weekend seasonality or not in the data
I have also checked the stationarity of data using adf test

Any suggestions on how I can enhance it further will be helpful

Thanks!!

I used MSTL to get the seasonal decompose then checked whether data is stationary or not and also checked acf whether it has significant drops on weekly lags